# How do I get List from JSON response using Retrofit

Tags: java, android, api, retrofit

How do I get the list from the json response? I've alreade get some data from json objects, but not from List, not sure how do I do that

Api

```
@GET("weather")
Call<List<Model>> getNewestForecast(
        @Query("lat") Double latitude,
        @Query("lon") Double longitude,
        @Query("appid") String key);
```

POJO

```
@SerializedName("weather")
private List<Weather> weather;

public List<Weather> getWeather() {
    return weather;
}

class Weather{
    @SerializedName("icon")
    private String forecastIcon;

    public String getForecastIcon() {
        return forecastIcon;
    }
}
```

JSON response

```
"weather": [
{
  "id": 520,
  "main": "Rain",
  "description": "light intensity shower rain",
  "icon": "09n"
}
 ]
```

How exactly should look like the reotrofit onResponse method?

Comment: for example which data you want to get from the list?

Comment: Gosh, again forgot to add the response, sorry about that. I'd like to have just the icon data.

Comment: doesn't Android Studio offer code completition with the onResponse?